# Ada: tagged type---inheritance from parent package

Tags: inheritance, ada

I am trying to understand tagged types and code extensions and reuse. I first create a program `conventional_method_number_of_averages` which implements one method for doing some calculation. Then I use extension of the tagged type and create a second program `alternative_method_number_of_averages` which implements a different method for solving the same problem. The difference is that now I have an additional `parameter`called `overlap_fraction`. Here is the simple program with the first method `conventional_method_number_of_averages` that works fine:

1. **number_of_averages.ads**

   ```
   with Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   package Number_Of_Averages renames Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```
2. **conventional_method_number_of_averages.ads**

   ```
   package Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages is

   type First_Method is tagged private;

   procedure Count_Averages (Any_Method : in out First_Method; Sampling_Frequency, FFT_Size, Time_Recorded: in Float);

   function Average_Is (Any_Method : in First_Method) return Float;

   private
   type First_Method is tagged
     record
        Number_Of_Averages : Float :=0.0;
      end record;

   end Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```
3. **conventional_method_number_of_averages.adb**

   ```
   package body Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages is

   procedure Count_Averages (Any_Method : in out First_Method; Sampling_Frequency, FFT_Size, Time_Recorded: in Float) is
   begin
       Any_Method.Number_Of_Averages := (((Sampling_Frequency * Time_Recorded) - FFT_Size)*(2.0/FFT_Size)) + 1.0;
   end Count_Averages;

   function Average_Is (Any_Method : in First_Method) return Float is
   begin
       return Any_Method.Number_Of_Averages;
   end;

   end Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```
4. and the test file **test_number_of_averages.adb**

   ```
   with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
   with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

   with Number_Of_Averages;
   with Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   use type Number_Of_Averages.First_Method;
   procedure Test_Number_Of_Averages is

   Fs, Time_Duration, NFFT    : Float := 0.0;
   Averages                   : Float := 0.0;

   Good_Method : Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.First_Method;

   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the sampling frequency ");
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Fs);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the time recorded ");
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Time_Duration);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the FFT size ");
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => NFFT);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);

      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line(1);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put("Number of averages = ");
      Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Good_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration);

      Averages := Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Average_Is(Good_Method);
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Averages, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);

   end Test_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```

The above works fine as it is.

Now if I create an alternative method for the same calculation, I have:

1. its specification **alternative_method_number_of_averages.ads**

   ```
   with Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   use Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;

   package Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages is

   type Second_Method is new First_Method with private;

   --override this function
   procedure Count_Averages (Any_Method : in out Second_Method; Sampling_Frequency, FFT_Size, Time_Recorded, Overlap_Fraction: in Float);


   private
   type Second_Method is new First_Method with
     record
        Overlap_Fraction : Float :=0.5;
     end record;

   end Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```

and

1. its body **alternative_method_number_of_averages.adb**

   ```
   package body Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages is

   --override this function
   procedure Count_Averages (Any_Method : in out Second_Method; Sampling_Frequency, FFT_Size, Time_Recorded, Overlap_Fraction: in Float) is
   begin
      Any_Method.Number_Of_Averages := ((Sampling_Frequency * Time_Recorded) - FFT_Size) / (FFT_Size - Overlap_Fraction * FFT_Size) + 1.0;
   end Count_Averages;


   end Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   ```

Then on compiling the specification file, I get the error message:

alternative_method_number_of_averages.ads: no selector "number_of_averages" for type "Second_Method" defined at alternative_method_of_averages.ads. The culprit line is:

```
     Any_Method.Number_Of_Averages := ((Sampling_Frequency * Time_Recorded) - FFT_Size) / (FFT_Size - Overlap_Fraction * FFT_Size) + 1.0;
```

So how to fix this?

In the end I would like to be able to have something like:

```
     Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Alternative_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration, Overlap_fraction);
```

in the test file **test_number_of_averages.adb**, similarly as the working code

```
     Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Good_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration);
```

Thanks a lot...

**UPDATE**

So now for the alternative method implementation, I have, renamed **Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.ads/adb** to **Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages-Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.ads/adb**. The test file is:

```
   with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
   with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

   with Number_Of_Averages;
   with Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages;
   use type Number_Of_Averages.First_Method;

   with Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages;

   procedure Test_Number_Of_Averages is

   Fs, Time_Duration, NFFT    : Float := 0.0;
   Averages1                   : Float := 0.0;
   Averages2                   : Float := 0.0;

   Good_Method                 : Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.First_Method;
   Alternative_Method          : Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Second_Method;

   begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the sampling frequency ");
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Fs);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the time recorded ");
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Time_Duration);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the FFT size ");
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => NFFT);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line(1);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put("Number of averages = ");
   Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Good_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration);

   Averages1 := Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Average_Is(Good_Method);
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Averages1, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line(1);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put("Number of averages = ");

   Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Alternative_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration); 
   Averages2 := Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Average_Is(Alternative_Method); 
   Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Averages2, Fore => 3, Aft  => 5, Exp  => 0);

   end Test_Number_Of_Averages;
```

With Fs = 48000, Time_Duration = 60, NFFT = 8192, both methods are returning 702.125. The second method though is always returning 702.125 irrespective of the `Overlap_Fraction` parameter. How to specify `Overlap_Fraction` in the calling function, while still keeping using it private i.e. by having the function use the value of `Overlap_Fraction` stored in the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the body of `Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages` you are trying to use `Number_Of_Averages`, which is a private member of the parent type. And since it is private,
you don't have visibility of it.

When you with a package you get visibility of the public part of the spec only.

A child package will have visibility of the public part of the parent in its own public part, and visibility of the private part of the parent in its own private part.

There's also private childs, which have visibility of the whole parent in its own spec

To get visibility of `Number_Of_Averages`, you can either move the full type declaration to the public part, or make `Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages` a child package of `Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Average`s.

For more details, take a look at: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Packages

On another note, overriding occurs only when a type extension is implementing a subprogram with the same exact parameter profile as in the parent. In your example, `Second_Method` is overloading `Count_Averages`, ie, adding a new subprogram with the same name but different profile. `Count_Averages` is still inherited from the parent with the shorter parameter profile.

Comment: @ egilhh. Thanks. How to make Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages a child package of Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages? I would prefer to keep Number_Of_Averages as private. 1 vote up.

Comment: Change the package name to: "package Conventional_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages is". You may also have to change the file name.

Comment: @ egilhh Thanks. I made the necessary changes but the result from the alternative method gives a zero, which is not right (though the formula is good). I have updated the post.

Comment: I don't see a call to Count_Averages for the Alternative_Method, so Average_Is will just return the default value of Number_Of_Averages, which is 0.0.

Comment: @ egilhh Yes your are right. I've put `Number_Of_Averages.Alternative_Method_Number_Of_Averages.Count_Averages(Alternative_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration);` but I am getting the same value of 702.125 irrespective of which `Overlap_Fraction` has. So there is still something not working right.

Comment: Like I said in my first answer, there is a difference between overloading and overriding. You are now calling a subprogram inherited from the parent. If you want to call the overloaded subprogram in the child, you will need to add a value for the Overlap_Fraction parameter. But looking at the rest of your code, you probably want to remove Overlap_Fraction from the parameter list, and use the record member declared for Second_Method.

Comment: How to specify the parameter `Overlap_Fraction` in `Count_Averages(Alterna‌​tive_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration)` for the Alternative method? But yes, I would like to use the `Overlap_Fraction` declared in the record. But if it is private, then how to go about perhaps without mentionning an `Overlap_Fraction` in the calling function? Is this possible?

Comment: To add avalue for the Overlap_Fraction parameter, just add another parameter at the point of call: Count_Averages(Alternative_Method, Fs, NFFT, Time_Duration, 0.5);   To use the record member, write Any_Method.Overlap_Fraction instead of just Overlap_Fraction in the body of Count_Averages. The last alternative here is most likely what you want.

Comment: Then you didn't put it inside the body (implementation) of Count_Averages: procedure Count_Averages (Any_Method : in out Second_Method; Sampling_Frequency, FFT_Size, Time_Recorded) is
begin
   Any_Method.Number_Of_Averages := ((Sampling_Frequency * Time_Recorded) - FFT_Size) / (FFT_Size - Any_Method.Overlap_Fraction * FFT_Size) + 1.0;
end Count_Averages;
Also note that I removed Overlap_Fraction as a parameter here, so Count_Averages will override the parent subprogram, and enable dynamic dispatching.

Comment: @ egilhh Thanks a lot. In addition to what you wrote above, I needed to change the specification file also i.e. to remove the parameter `Overlap_Fraction`.